# Variational Autoencoder - When do we need to marginalize over the latent variables?

Tags: probability

I am a non Engineering student trying to understand variational autoencoders with very little background in probability and statistics. I am following the tutorial here https://jaan.io/what-is-variational-autoencoder-vae-tutorial/ with code on the MNIST dataset.

1. I don't understand the need to marginalize over the latent variable z when computing `p(x|z)p(z)`. I understand the code very well and in it, p(z) is first computed by sampling from a normal distribution before it is sent through a neural network to generate the image i.e. compute p(x|z). Why don't we need to marginalize over the latent variable z here in the code?
2. In terms of maths, I understand the need to marginalize over the latent variables but why is it not being done in the code?
3. $\frac{p(x|z)p(z)}{p(x)}$ is intractable because we need to marginalize over the latent variable z for the denominator $\sum_z p(x,z)$. What about the numerator $p(z)$ and $p(x|z)$ ? Why do we not need to marginalize over z? We don't know what z is right?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, they wish to marginalize over $z$ to incorporate all the information provided by the prior distribution $p(z)$. Recall that marginalization is simply integration, and so we can reformulate integrating over $z$ to be similar to the logic used with how fully Bayesian methods define their posterior (or prior) predictive distributions.